# How can I make an image gallery using php/javascript/css?

Tags: php, css, image, gallery

What I have done so far:

```
<div class="gallery">
<?php

$postimg[]= "";
$postimg = DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts where user_id=:userid ORDER BY 
posted_at desc ' ,array(':userid'=>$userid));

foreach($postimg as $img)
{
echo "<a href=".$img['postimg']."><img  src='".$img['postimg']."' 
height='300' width='300'></a>";

  echo "<div class='gallery'>
  <img class='image' src='".$img['postimg']."'>
  <div class='overlay'>hover test</div>";
}
?>
```

The images are shown but I have a problem with the css and it seems that I can not do a lot of things.

To be more specific, I tried adding a hover effect on every image but when I hover over an image, the hovers of all images appear at the bottom of the page. Furthermore, the images are very small.

Here is my css code:

```
.gallery img {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: .3s;
    padding: 13px;
}


.gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}



.overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1; 
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

So here comes my question: Is my DB question not right and all the hovers appear at the same time? Is it a total css fault? (I have 0 css knowledge)

[Here is a a photo of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyfF7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your hover is happening at once because you have invalid html. You have a bunch of open-ended `<div>` tags:

```
<!-- START GALLERY -->
<div class="gallery">

<?php
$postimg[]= "";
$postimg = DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts where user_id=:userid ORDER BY 
posted_at desc ' ,array(':userid'=>$userid));

foreach($postimg as $img) {
    echo "<a href=".$img['postimg']."><img  src='".$img['postimg']."' 
height='300' width='300'></a>";
    # START GALLERY AGAIN
    echo "<div class='gallery'>
    <img class='image' src='".$img['postimg']."'>
    <div class='overlay'>hover test</div>";
    # NO GALLERY END!!
}
?>
<!-- NO GALLERY END!! -->
```

First, I might create a function on a different page and include it once at the top of the page at page load. That way you can clean up your view and make this re-usable (creating this function is more of a suggestion than a requirement).

**/functions/getImagesById.php**

```
<?php
function getImagesById($userid)
{
    $result = DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts where user_id=:userid ORDER BY 
posted_at desc ' ,array(':userid'=>$userid));
    return (!empty($result))? $result : [];
}
```

You script should be more like:

```
<?php
# Include function
include_once("/functions/getImagesById.php");
# Loop through the returned array
foreach(getImagesById($userid) as $img): ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $img['postimg'] ?>"><img  src='<?php echo $img['postimg'] ?>' height='300' width='300' /></a>
    <!-- START THIS GALLERY -->
    <div class='gallery'>
        <img class='image' src='<?php echo $img['postimg'] ?>' />
        <div class='overlay'>hover test</div>";
    </div>
    <!-- END THIS GALLERY -->

<?php endforeach ?>
```